# Changing floating toolbar orientation

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, toolbar

Is there a way, within QGIS 2.*, to stop the interface from trying to snap in floating toolbars (as attached pic)?

I want to maximise canvas space, but the interface keeps on wanting to grab my toolbars.

[image]

Comment: Docking toolbars to the left and right side is possible, if that is what you are after. If not, please add a screenshot how it should look like. You can as well stack several toolbars in one row, or remove those you don't use.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to try and stop a toolbar from being docked by the interface, most programmes require the the toolbar to be positioned over the menu areas before it's docked, QGIS seems to want to grab and dock from quite a distance away.

Comment: Calcification: Qt want to grab and dock. QGIS itself doesn't handle any of that logic